# Ninject with MVC 5, ObjectContext diposed after JSON call

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

I made my previous research, and from all the Ninject posts (that I've found), and its GitHub's documentation, this is the closest thread for my problem: [DbContext Disposed after first request when using Ninject's InRequestScope()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149804/dbcontext-disposed-after-first-request-when-using-ninjects-inrequestscope)

My situation is framed from a different perspective. The difference is that I am not using ActionFilters; I am making JSON calls inside the ASP.NET server (through JSON.NET) to an external application. Apparently this changes the request scope and Ninject ditches the context altogether.

I am using Ninject with MVC 5 and Identity 2.0. I have the context called "AppIdentityDbContext". I am using the Repository pattern, in which I inject the context through constructor injection, and then expose its properties through IDbSet<>:

I currently have the context managed through an .InRequestScope():

```
kernel.Bind<AppIdentityDbContext>().To<AppIdentityDbContext>().InRequestScope();
```

The application works if I remove the .InRequestScope(). But (correct me if I'm wrong), for performance considerations, [I shall leave the InRequestScope so Ninject manages it for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592419/1057052).

The closest solution I've found is to create another class that implements the AppIdentityDbContext and create a specific implementation to the method I'm using to call the JSON call. The problem with the solution is the level of (unnecessary) complexity that will add to my application.

Other solution would be to manually dispose the context, but that could create verbose code on the long run.

What could be an efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you find the place where it is incorrectly disposed? Can you post the stack to that place?

Comment: @Steven: Now I can't reproduce the problem. What the heck is going on?!  I'll post back if the error pops up again.... -_-